# How to cache and store Shopify cart items?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, shopify

I Know that already this Question asked in past. But Not get Proper Answer and Solution i think.

So,

I'm using mobile buy sdk to integrate Shopify in my app. 
I add product to the cart by using

```
[self.cart addVariant:self.productVariant];
```

But my problem is whenever I close and open the app means cart shows empty.

Every time i get lineitem object nill.

So, How can i solved it ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

That is because sdk doesn't keep track of cart items,we have to do it manually. The way I solved this problem is I stored the product id in the local database. When ever I close and open the app I get the product id from local database and call a function buyclient.getproductbyid(product_id); Then I get product variant and then add it cart.

Comment: productid with all the product details right ? can i store whole Buycart or lineitem array details in database ?

Comment: And More query is that, How can i get total and subtotal value in cartlistview ? That manage by the sdk or calculate from our side ? Please give me clear solution....

Comment: you can get it from cart methods